# how to display the output in plist format. Is it possible or not? and also the Data in textarea should be able to download?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
      <textarea id="area" style="height:200px;width:80%">
          Hello Everyone.
          Entry name 2.
          rahul
          mahesh</textarea>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

 <script>
 function pad(num, diff) {
    return diff > 0 ? pad(num, diff - 1) + 0 : num;
 }

 function processString(num) {
    var tmp = num.replace(/\.+/g, '');
    var diff = 4 - tmp.length;
    var tmpl = '<string>#{padded}</string>';
    var padded = diff > 0 ? pad(tmp, diff).split('').join('.') : num;
    return tmpl.replace('#{padded}', padded);
  }

  var button = document.getElementById('submit');
  button.addEventListener('click', processArea);

  function processArea() {
     var area = document.getElementById('area')
     var arr = area.value.split(/\n/);
     for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
     arr[i] = processString(arr[i]);
   }
   area.value = arr.join('\r\n');
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For reference See http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/15/

From Above Fiddle it is generating the list properly,but I need the generated List should be in .plist format.

can Anyone Help me out.

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library
/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<array>
<string>Hello Everyone.</string>
<string>Entry name 2.</string>
<string>rahul</string>
<string>mahesh</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Current Output:

```
<string>Hello Everyone.</string>
<string>Entry name 2.</string>
<string>rahul</string>
<string>mahesh</string>
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using this [plist plugin](http://dpearson.me/plist.js/).

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: did you try fill out header and footer part yourself

Comment: @sam100rav

 Can you please explain it with example,how to use it.

can you provide a demo with fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/16/

Comment: @engincancan not able to use or add header and footer to this code.

can you please help me, how to use it.

Comment: you are using simple line break divider not much complex logic so it should be easy but where you are gonna use it. Show a use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add header and footer as string syntax as follows. You can call the function `saveTextAsFile` to download. Tested on chrome

```
function processArea() {
    var area = document.getElementById('area');
    var arr = area.value.split(/\n/);
    var header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">\n<plist version="1.0">\n<dict>\n<array>';
    var footer = '\n</array>\n</plist>';
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
      arr[i] = processString(arr[i]);
    }
    area.value = header+arr.join('\r\n')+footer;
}

function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById('area').value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "ecc.plist";/*Your file name*/

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/19/)

Comment: can we add save option to this ,so that from there i can save the data mentioned in text area.

Comment: it is not an easy task to do it with client side but there is some workaround about it

Comment: edit your question and i will add function to download but i did tested only chrome

Comment: Hello @engincancan How to use that Code

Not able to use it  on click "Save" button

Comment: check the link again http://jsfiddle.net/1csov2s1/19/ or you could call function on click event of your button

Comment: Great Hats OFF Sir ji

Really Yaar, Its Working Perfectly.